# Android Accessibility : characters announced twice

Tags: android, android-edittext, talkback, accessibility

Precondition : Accessibility Talkback on.

Problem : While typing in characters from soft keyboard into the edit text, the characters are announced twice.
(I think once by the keyboard and once by the edit text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: Sighted users don't understand/empathize well with the types of information that blind users need. They just use a keyboard with TalkBack on, without actually closing their eyes and experiencing it the way a blind or partially sighted user would.

Solution: Close your eyes and actually use the keyboard the same way a TalkBack user would. You will discover that there are actually two relevant pieces of information here. The key that you're going to select and the key that you've actually selected.

Real Solution: Let Android do its thing unless you REALLY know what you're doing. More often than not, well intentioned, developers just muck things up when they start trying too hard. Provide content descriptions for your non-text controls, hook up some nice data associations when necessary and otherwise leave things alone.